# they come from around Austin

Tags: meaning, prepositions, adverbial-phrases

a. Our customers come from around Austin.

b. Our customers come from all around Austin.

Do those sentences mean

1. They come from different places in Austin
2. They come from places near Austin (but not from Austin itself)
3. They come from Austin and places close to it

?

Comment: They don't have a fixed meaning. Personally, I would understand both to mean 'from the surrounding area'. I would use _all over Austin_ to mean 'different places in the city'.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/around) defines "around" as meaning "near" in "around Chicago", while also giving other meanings such as "here and there in or throughout". By its nature "all around" doesn't have a precise meaning, it just means multiple places in the vicinity.